# How to display specific html page using php authentication without database?

Tags: php, html, forms-authentication

Being new to php, I'm trying to display a specific html page using simple php authentication without database. I store different usernames and passwords in logins array. I want to display a different page for each username. For example `if isset[Username]= Marc header("location:marc.html")`

**login.html**

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="Login_Form">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">
    <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><h3>Client identification</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"></td>
      <td><input name="Username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td><input name="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Enter" class="Button3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    /* Check Login form submitted */    
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

        /* Define username and associated password array */
        $logins = array(
                    'Marc' => 'pass','username1' => 'password1',
                    'Guy' => 'pass','username2' => 'password2',
                    'Lucie' => 'pass','username3' => 'password3',
                    'Eva' => 'pass','username4' => 'password4');

        /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

        /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){

                    /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
            header("location:marc.html");
            exit;
        } else {
            /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cool. What's not working?

Comment: How can you have php code in a html file?

Comment: `header("location:".strtolower($Username).".html");`?

Comment: You should check BEFORE redirecting if the datas are correct. Use javascript to check if the data are filled or not. THEN send to the php page. Checking if the data are filled isn't a job for PHP. You should have `$Username =  $_POST['Username'];`

Comment: so why not store the name of the page you want to redirect to in that logins array? then it's just a matter of `header("Location: $logins[page]");`

Comment: @MarcB: I just started learning PHP few hours ago, would you mind showing full code example please? Thanks

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: I need it to be a specific page according to username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance i expect you need:

```
 header("location:marc.html");
```

changing to:

```
 $url = strtolower($Username);
 header("location:".$url.".html");
```

Comment: My bad... I should of tried your solution before saying anything... Its actually just what I needed! Thank you!